# How to use the Oracle Spatial functions inside ms4w MAPFILE DATA string?

Tags: mapserver, oracle-spatial, ms4w

How to use Oracle Spatial functions in the DATA queries of MapServer(ms4w 3.0.3)? I am getting the following error while trying to highlight selected features which lie inside a particular boundary :

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named
>   'thematic_layer'. msOracleSpatialLayerWhichShapes(): OracleSpatial
>   error. Error parsing OracleSpatial DATA variable.

Following is the query I am using in the DATA string :

```
DATA "geom from (select S.XFM_ID as XFM_ID,S.LOCATION as LOCATION,S.OGC_GEOMETRY as geom from STRAND S,NODEBOUNDARY NB where SDO_RELATE(S.OGC_GEOMETRY,NB.OGC_GEOMETRY,'mask=inside')='TRUE' and NB.NODENAME='PUGA2003' and S.LOCATION in ('A','2')) as FOO USING UNIQUE XFM_ID SRID 2622 VERSION 10g"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the '*as FOO*' statement at the end of the select statement, it is not needed.

As a reference this is the template for an Oracle Spatial DATA definition with a select instruction:

```
'geometry_column FROM (SELECT stmt) [USING UNIQUE <column> SRID srid# FUNCTION]'
```

the parts in square parenthesis are optional.

Reference retrieved straight from the [source](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/blob/master/maporaclespatial.c#L1853).

Comment: Thanx Unicoletti. That worked.